# How to fix error: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at > '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)?

Tags: macos, server.app, profile-manager

On a 10.7 (10.7.5 to be precise) Mac OS X Server machine, there are repeated error messages in Console:

> ProfileManager: Unable to create ProfileManager log file at
>   '/var/log/devicemgr/profilemanager.log' (No such file or directory)

Path `/var/log/devicemgr` does not exist.

How to fix this error and thus remove the message from console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was this command in Terminal.app:

```
$ sudo /bin/ln -s /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Logs/ /var/log/devicemgr
```

With thanks to the "fix-profileManager.sh" script posting at:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3412734?tstart=0